# Text in Windows-Form is marked after changed with function

Tags: c#, text, insert, textbox

i created a windows-form with a multi-line textbox and an OK-button.
The content of the textbox can be changed with a function.
        public void SetTextBox(string box)
        {
            textbox.Text = box;
        }

It works fine, the only problem is that the complete text in the textbox is marked after inserted. I dont understand why it is marked.

Thanks for help how to make it unmark

Answer (score 1):

I feel that your text box is getting focus when that function gets called, so focus makes the text selected or marked.

Try changing the tab index of the textbox after changing the text.

Comment: Great. Now it works. 
The TabIndex was 0, i changed it to 1.
The Ok-button was 1 and is now 0
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by marked, if you mean selected, try this.

```
textBox1.Select(0, 0);
```

first zero being the starting index and the second being the target index, you can also use it to select specific indexes on the string